# SAGA Tool in QGIS Error: Load table: Proj.4-WKT Dictionary... failed

Tags: qgis, saga, osgeo4w, qgis-2.12

I have some problems with running SAGA tools in QGIS. I've downloaded and installed the software via the OSGeo4W Installer. It downloaded QGIS 2.12 and Saga 2.1.2. I wanted to use the Tool "Shapes To Grid" to convert a Point Feature to a Raster but I've always got the Error that the "gdal_MrSID.dll" wasn't able to load although the dll was in the folder. So I tried installing the latest SAGA Version 2.2.2 64bit, set the right path in QGIS and then it worked!
Afterwards I tried to use the "Change Grid Values" Tool but it didn't work. I got some errors:

Load table: Proj.4-WKT Dictionary...
failed

And later:

Error: select a library

That is very strange because the Tool works perfectly with the path set to Saga 2.1.2. I guess it has something to do with path settings but I don't know how I could solve this.

Has anyone an idea what could cause this? I am very new to SAGA and QGIS. I used ArcGIS before. If you need any more information about the problem, my system or my paths I will tell them to you. Right know I don't really know what information could be useful for this topic.